# Is collection.find().toArray() an asyncronus method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb-query

I have to apply forEach() method on array returned by collection.find().toArray().

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's async, so you'd use it like this:

```
collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
  if (err) ...handle error...
  // `results` is a JS array
  results.forEach(...);
});
```

Or like this, using promises:

```
collection.find().toArray().then(function(results) {
  results.forEach(...);
}).catch(function(err) {
  ...handle error...
});
```

Comment: does it return a promise?

Comment: Yes, it does, I _just_ added the code for that as well ;D